# Channel Google App Engine channel.open() does not work

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, channel-api

I've a problem when opening the channel.
i've this on the server side:

```
   def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if not user:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))
            return
        channel_id=str(str(random.randint(0,1000)))
        token = channel.create_channel(channel_id)
        template_values = {
                           'token': token,
                           'me': user.user_id()
                           }

        logger.debug("Token: %s user:%s %s %s" % (token,user.user_id(),user.nickname(),user.email()))
        self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/index.html', template_values))
```

and this on the HTML (templates/index.html)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body>
    {{ token }}
    <script>alert("a0");
        var token = {{ token }};
        alert("a1");
        var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
        alert("a2");
        var socket = channel.open();
        alert("a3");


        socket.onopen = function(){
            alert("open");
        };

        socket.onmessage = function(m){
            var data = $.parseJSON(m.data);
            alert(data)
        };
        socket.onerror =  function(err){
            alert("Error => "+err.description);
        };
        socket.onclose =  function(){
            alert("channel closed");
        };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put alert to see if everything works, but a0 a1 a2 are raised, while a3 doesn't.
Where is the problem?
why channel.open() does not work?

PS: is there any way to trace these errors in javascript ? something more effective then guessing where is the error.

Comment: There's Firebug for Firefox or you can use the built-in Javascript debugger for Chrome, Opera, etc. There's also a Javascript console in most browsers that shows errors.

Comment: i thought this as well, but i don't see "open" as alert as well. so the channel seems to not be opened.
I'm actually trying to get the /_ah/channel/connected/ data, but i don't really get how it works

Comment: Are you using the Google App Engine documentation?

Comment: for what? for the connected/disconnected? i'm reading it right now.
i added this 
 `- url: /_ah/channel/connected/.*
  script: handlers_connect.app`

which leads to this class 

`import webapp2
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

class Channel(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        client_id = self.request.get('from')
        logger.debug("client id %s" % client_id)
        return 

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/.*', Channel)],
                              debug=True)`

but nothing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging use either Firebug or the Chrome debugger.  You can log messages to the console by adding lines into your Javascript:

```
window.console.log("Message")
```

Double check that the value you get for 'token' is indeed the correct token.

Comment: actually the problem is that i miss the ' ' around {{ token }} but even with this the function for onopen is not raised.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but the callback might be missed because the browser is waiting for you to click on one of the other asserts.

Comment: even removing the alert before the one inside the onOpened is not raised. 
is it normal that the channel (token) is changed everytime i refresh the page?

Comment: I would say "no, it's not normal", as in, you shouldn't do that.  But yes, it's expected in your case because in your get() handler you create a new token on every request.

Comment: also, verify that channel.open() is returning with a valid socket object, that might explain why your onopen() is not called.

Comment: how can i verify if it is or not a valid socket?

Comment: Use the debugger, do you get a valid object out of channel.open()?

Comment: the debugger says ok for the channel but complains about onOpened saying that is not defined (but it's defined!).
Actually i was doing smt like this `  socket.onopen = onOpened;
  onOpened = function() {
   alert('we are open');
  };
` and this is not working (why?)

Comment: You need to define onOpened first before assigning to it.  If you post your actual code, it would be much easier to tell.  Anyways, your original question has been answered.

Comment: If you aren't already using Chrome as your browser, I highly recommend it for debugging Javascript.  Here's the documentation for the debugger which is built in, it makes debugging issues like yours pretty easy: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/overview.  I can see how it would be frustrating debugging with only alerts.  That's very 2002.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem. It ran fine on local host, but did not work once I uploaded it. It appears that the tokens don't always start formatted correctly, and you need to trim them.

Thus the following alerts with "1", but then crashes:

```
if(user != null)
{
    $.get("tutorial",{channelKey:userId} ,function(data) {alert(data); token = data;
    alert(userId);
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(data);
    alert(1);
    socket = channel.open();
    alert(2);
    socket.onopen = onOpened;
    alert(3);
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    alert(4);
    socket.onerror = onError;
    alert(5);
    socket.onclose = onClose;
    alert(6);
});
```

If you change this to:

```
if(user != null)
{
    $.get("tutorial",{channelKey:userId} ,function(data) {alert(data); token = data;
    alert(userId);
    channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(data.trim());
    alert(1);
    socket = channel.open();
    alert(2);
    socket.onopen = onOpened;
    alert(3);
    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    alert(4);
    socket.onerror = onError;
    alert(5);
    socket.onclose = onClose;
    alert(6);
});
```

However, it works perfectly and opens the channel!

Comment: Brilliant! Fixed my problem too.